# Looking for a comic with a jester, the Grim Reaper and a rose

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm looking for a comic story I read in the late 90s / early 2000s.

It featured:

- a jester-type character (face painted white)
- Death / the Grim Reaper
- Something about a rose and an hour-glass

The graphical style had exaggerated ink lines that frequently overshot the shapes, giving it an edged/"corner-y" look.

The theme was mystical/fantasy-ish, with the group looking for the rose or something like that.

The story, or possibly only a part of it, was bundled in those [Gespenster Geschichten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gespenster_Geschichten) (or similar) pulp horror comics in Germany.

It was neither Neil Gaiman's Sandman, nor the Dark Tower comics. These are unfortunately the only thing I can find with googling.

Comment: Just to clarify, was it a comic story in that it was a story which was humourous, or that it was a comic book (panels of drawings, speech bubbles and such)?

Comment: It was the latter, with drawn panels and speech bubbles. :)

Comment: How was Death portrayed?  Male or female? Young, old? Hooded and cloaked? Dressed normally?  How did you know they were Death? Did they carry a scythe?

Comment: I *think* it was a hooded skeleton. I don't remember a scythe, but an hourglass and a book.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it was Neil Gaiman's "[Harlequin Valentine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harlequin_Valentine)" ?

[image]

> The tale begins on February 14th, when Harlequin nails his heart to the door of Missy, a woman he has decided is his Columbine. While Missy sees the heart, and removes it from her door to place it in a plastic sandwich baggy, she cannot see the capering Harlequin, who stalks her footsteps as she tries to discover the source of this rather unusual Valentine's Day present. The subsequent events revolve around what Missy does with Harlequin's heart now that she has it, while Harlequin follows her around and falls ever more deeply in love.

As you can see it contains jester-type character (the Harlequin). However, I don't recall Death, rose and hour glass.

Comment: Nope, sorry, that doesn't seem to be it.